# How to compare an Fedora iso download file with its sha-256 checksum text file in Windows using Java?

Tags: java, powershell, checksum, iso, sha256

I wanted to verify the sha256-checksum of the Fedora ISO image I have downloaded with its checksum text file. I have the iso and checksum text file both on a directory. And I followed the Fedora verifying downloaded image (https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/Installation_Guide/sect-verifying-images.html) instructions for Windows and got an error "The file is too long, this operation is currently limited to supporting files less than 2 gigabytes in size" while using Windows8.1 powershell. The ISO image file is 2.165GB size. Is there a Java api or tool available now so that I don't have to reinvent the wheel? I don't have a Linux/

Comment: Well have you tried using the Java `MessageDigest` class? (You should be able to do it with PowerShell using a more sensible API, to be honest - it's crazy that they're using `File.ReadAllBytes` rather than calling `ComputeHash(Stream)`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Powershell 4.0 or greater (which you are since you said you are using Windows 8.1), you can utilize the Get-FileHash cmdlet. Example:

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 .\en_visual_studio_enterprise_2015_x86_x64_dvd_6850497.iso
```

Comment: Thank you for that command, it works and verified that I have a genuine Fedora. Tks again.

Comment: @JPBlanc, I tried up vote this (if that's what you mean by good answer) and I got an message stating that I don't have enough reputations (15?) to do so.

Comment: You shoud just put it as the answer (answered).

Answer (score 0):

[The Fedora documentation has you covered](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Burning_ISO_images_to_disc/sect-Burning_ISO_images_to_disc-Validating_the_Files-Validating_in_the_Windows_Graphical_Environment.html) (and I guess you need a reference to it).

Keep in mind that the documentation typically lags a little in the non-core items, so if you find that the latest release is missing a document that you've become accustomed to finding, look one or two releases back (as I did in this case).

There are both Windows GUI and Windows CLI verification methods, with references to a number of utilities to calculate the sha256sum

Answer (score 0):

I can't totally tell if the question is using additional software to fully automate the actual comparison of the two hashes. It doesn't seem like it is, so I think it could benefit from this one liner:

```
get-filehash ./relativeLocationOfFileToCompare | select -expandproperty hash | compare-object theHashYouWantToCompare
```

i.e.

```
get-filehash -Algorithm SHA256 .\en_visual_studio_enterprise_2015_x86_x64_dvd_6850497.iso | select -expandproperty hash | compare-object 64f6ca69ccb3efc79e350977d33109c380a744c26158c4e3956141535242e2ca
```

if there is no output, the checksums match.